# Let's get critical: Dec 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Movies & TV Stack Exchange](http://movies.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: tired of this evaluation. ..wana see graduation soon.

Comment: Yeah! Bring us freedom!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Why did the Joker choose Harvey Dent?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/15357/why-did-the-joker-choose-harvey-dent)

**Net Score: 14** (Excellent: 15, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Cartoon with a muscular main character who's wearing sunglasses](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/15195/cartoon-with-a-muscular-main-character-whos-wearing-sunglasses)

**Net Score: 13** (Excellent: 13, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Why did Cass distrust the Doctor?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/15247/why-did-cass-distrust-the-doctor)

**Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 11, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How did Bane know the exact location of the Batmobile?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/14917/how-did-bane-know-the-exact-location-of-the-batmobile)

**Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 14, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Why was Tony Stark so sure that Banner would return to fight?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/15376/why-was-tony-stark-so-sure-that-banner-would-return-to-fight)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 16, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Was Dr. Lecter really cooking human flesh?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/15428/was-dr-lecter-really-cooking-human-flesh)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 13, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Ending to Memento](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/14866/ending-to-memento)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 13, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Movie in which people go to a forest and build their new home but are killed by tree spirits](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/15304/movie-in-which-people-go-to-a-forest-and-build-their-new-home-but-are-killed-by)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Movie about a man and his daughter that move to the countryside after wife has committed suicide](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/15441/movie-about-a-man-and-his-daughter-that-move-to-the-countryside-after-wife-has-c)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Doctor enters the minds of coma patients](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/15007/doctor-enters-the-minds-of-coma-patients)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 11, Needs Improvement: 6)

---